# how to have a max height on my div.main class

Tags: css, bootstrap-grid

on my website (using zenphoto and boostrap 3), I have an issue on my div.main class.
http://test.vincentbourganel.fr

I have static navbar and a fixed footer on the bottom.
I want the div.main have "a height of 100% of the rest of the remaing place".
It doesn't work when my content don't take all the remaing height.

See this page as example :
http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/page/contact/

Can you help me to slove this issue

Comment: Please post your code in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as ones your linked site changes or is dead the question becomes redundant and is most likely not going to be of help to anyone else.

Comment: I posted a working example check it.

Comment: as example; you can consider this code from bootply:
https://www.bootply.com/eW319k9Sh7

I want <div container main> to stick the footer in case of content is too small to fill the page.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you feel about this solution and I'm more a back end developer than front end guy but you could always do something like

`calc(100vh - (HEIGHT_OF_HEADER + BORDER) - (HEIGHT_OF_FOOTER + BORDER)`

Only thing I don't like about this solution is I can't think of a way to do it without hard coding the heights in there.  I'm sure there's a way to grab it but for now this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I found a way to do that in a side js file, with something like that :

`$(window).resize(function() {
 // Full height page - minus "header" and "footer" height
 $('.full-page').innerHeight($(window).height() - $('#header').innerHeight() - $('#footer').innerHeight()); 
}).resize();`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using `flex`, I created a `box` class and assigned `flex` as a property, then use `flex:1 0 0` to content part, I used `position` to footer to stay in bottam, and assigned `overflow:auto` to content part div.

below i posted a working example to understanding

Flex - [Flex Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dy21mopw/1/)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi magnam iusto fugit illo omnis aperiam mollitia non fugiat, at in ratione harum ullam alias dicta, excepturi quod sed delectus veniam?<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Nisi magnam iusto fugit illo omnis aperiam mollitia non fugiat, at in ratione harum ullam alias dicta, excepturi quod sed delectus veniam?<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi magnam iusto fugit illo omnis aperiam
    mollitia non fugiat, at in ratione harum ullam alias dicta, excepturi quod sed delectus veniam?<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi magnam iusto fugit illo omnis aperiam mollitia non fugiat, at in ratione harum ullam
    alias dicta, excepturi quod sed delectus veniam?<br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks
I will consider your code.
Before that, I have a question : what is backward compatibility for flex property with older browsers?
As far I know, Bootstrap 3.x don't use it (it prefers table property ) and bootstrap 4 (alpha version) has been rewrited to implement flex property.

Comment: You can read here about `flex` to get better knowledge
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: If you consider IE browser then IE-8 or earlier not supported and rest browsers is comfortable with `flex` using `prifix` like `-webkit-`  and some of more

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to adjust the height of main div. It will display on full screen if the content is less.

`.main{
    min-height: 100vh;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I want in my js file.
My JS code fix min-height of my main div to fill the screen even if main content is small one.

this code is working fine to suit my need :

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // full height for main div (windows height - "header" height - "footer" height)
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#main').css('min-height', $(window).height() - $('#menu').outerHeight() - $('#footer').outerHeight());
    }).resize();
});`

You can see it in action there : 
http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/